# Give initial value to non-const member of super class? (C++)

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm wondering how I could have subclasses which have a non-const member that is initialized.  For example, I could have a superclass with private integer member 'index.'  When the subclass is initialized, I want 'index' to always start with the same value (0).

Since I want the subclass to have it's own constructor, where the future programmer may not know to initialize 'index' to 0, how can I make sure it starts with the desired value?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you make it protected then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just make the superclass initialize `index` to zero in its default constructor:

```
class SuperClass {
    int index;

public:
    SuperClass()
    : index(0)
    { }
};
```

Any subclass during construction will first call the constructor of all of its inherited classes - so as long as the superclass initializes its internals correctly, the subclasses will all inherit that.

Comment: Barry, this seems to be exactly what I'm looking for!  What is the term for 'index(0)' before the curly braces for the body of the constructor?

Comment: @John It's an [initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

Comment: What's the difference between the initializer list and initializing the values inside the body of the (superclass) constructor?

Comment: if you dont initialize your variables in initializer list, compiler will try to call default constructor for given object, but not all may have it defined, so it may result in compiler errors